# Eliminating duplicate entries in a two dimensional array in python 3

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.6, nested-lists

I'm not sure if this is the best way to approach the problem - I am very new, so I'll give you some background:

I've managed to create a program that scrapes a few websites for me and returns weather reports to me based upon particular criteria. Some of them are very similar, if not the same, and it's tedious still to scroll through a dozen or so reports for the same region. What would be more useful is if I could consolidate these reports into one, while adding the headers from each report.

What my program has done so far is it breaks down each report into:

- a header
- a warning type
- body text

These are pushed into a larger array with a length of [x] for the one dimension and of [3] for the other.

My figuring is if I could loop through the array and compare the body text of each. If the body text is dissimilar, it passes over it, but if they are the same, my program could add the header to the next one, and then delete that entry entirely.

The results are less than stellar. I've tried it a few different ways with mixed results, but this is what I have currently:

```
#Overall array as list
practice_array = []

#Sub lists
first_array = ["header 1", "warning", "body"]
second_array = ["header 2", "warning", "body"]
third_array = ["header 3", "warning", "body"]
fourth_array = ["header 4", "warning", "body"]
fifth_array = ["header 5", "warning", "body"]

#Values of practice_array
practice_array = [first_array, second_array, third_array, fourth_array,
fifth_array]

#Length of the loop
length = len(practice_array)

#Loop starts with the first item in the list 
for x in range(0, length):

    #The second loop starts with the next so it has something to compare
    for y in range(1, length):

        #If the body texts are the same then...
        if practice_array[x][2] == practice_array[y][2] :

             #Add the header to the other header
             practice_array[y][0] += (' ' + practice_array[x][0])

             #Delete the first item
             del practice_array[x]

             #Print for me to see
             print(practice_array[y][0])
```

IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: If you give a sample output, aka what you want the output to looks like structurally, someone can write you a list comprehension that will take care of this in one line. As is, hard to grasp what your end goal is.

Comment: Reading code, you are getting index error because you are deleting elements in array so array length won't be 5 anymore. So when you try to access to element practice_array[4][2] it will fail, because you have already removed one element

Comment: Using the above it'd look something like:

practice_array[0][0] "header 1 header 2 header 3 header 4 header 5"
practice_array[0][1] "warning"
practice_array[0][2] "body"

Comment: carlosvin, that's what I thought too. I'm not sure how to get around that and I don't think I'm approaching this problem the right way.

Comment: @MattK an easy solution is to use another data structure to create your result, a python dict can fit perfectly if your body is your identifier. I will try to write an example

Answer (score 0):

Your algorithm is checking each entry, and comparing it to every other entry. That will give you O(n^2) performance. You can reduce it to O(n) performance by first sorting on the text field. Then you'll only have to compare each pair of consecutive entries.

Comment: To be correct, if you sort a list in Python you will get O(n log n)

https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity

Comment: This goes beyond my capabilities right now. I only need it to work and then maybe I will look at optimizing it.

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in range(len(practice_array)):
    if len(practice_array[i]) == 0:
            continue
    for j in range(1, len(practice_array)):
        if len(practice_array[j]) == 0:
            continue
        if i != j and practice_array[i][2] == practice_array[j][2]:
            practice_array[i][0] += " {}".format(practice_array[j][0])
            practice_array[j] = []
practice_array = list(filter(lambda x: len(x) > 0, practice_array))
```

This is how you should do it. You must never remove items from list you're working on, let alone store its length in a variable and use it as a condition (when the actual length is decreasing). After comparison just replace each inner list with the same `body` with something simple which won't pass the filter condition so you can update your resulting list by picking only the items that you need (like here: we're replacing lists with same `body` with empty lists so we can filter them out later on).

Answer (score 0):

The `IndexError` is because you are changing your list size when deleting and trying to access elements out of range on posterior iterations.

Here is one possible solution for what I think you want to do

```
# Get all different body values
unique_body = set([i[2] for i in practice_array])

result = []
# Iterate over body values
for body in unique_body:
    # Get all entries have the same body value
    matching_entries = [i for i in practice_array if i[2] == body]

    # Join the headers
    header = ' '.join([i[0] for i in matching_entries])

    # Make a new entry and append it to a result list
    merged_entry = [header, matching_entries[0][1], body]
    result.append(merged_entry)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a dictionary to construct the result is easy to implement and you get O(n) time complexity. 
I hope I understood correctly what you want to achieve.

```
practice_dict = {}
for p in practice_array:
    body = p[2]
    if body in practice_dict:
        practice_dict[body][0] += (' ' + p[0])
    else:
        practice_dict[body] = p

print(practice_dict)
```

Output:

```
{'body': ['header 1 header 2 header 3 header 4 header 5', 'warning', 'body']}
```

You can use also a list, but it is a little bit less convenient

Answer (score 0):

You're getting the index error because you're changing the size of "practice_array" while looping through its contents, but you probably already know that.

To take advantage of built-in function speed, you could use convert practice_array into a set and back into a list with `new_array_1 = list(set(practice_array))`. This assumes you don't care about the order of the list, and this only eliminates identical arrays.

With or without the `set()` conversion, you could accumulate arrays with unique "body" elements (whether or not the headers and warnings are identical), in a new list if the "body" element of the list is not found in a list that accumulates "body" elements.

```
new_array_2 = []
body_els = []

for el in new_array_1:
    if el[2] in body_els:
        pass
    else:
        new_array_2.append(el)
        body_els.append(el[2])
```

At the end of the loop, `new_array_2` will be a list of arrays with unique body elements.